# Remove all the characters of the string that come after the "\" character in r

Tags: r, string

So I have a dataframe that has a column called "Player" which contains the name of the player. The problem is that the column has the following format:

Kobe Bryant\kobebryant
LeBron James\lebronjames
Kevin Durant\kevindurant

and so on.

I want to remove all the characters that come after the "" character, so I want to keep only "Kobe Bryant", "LeBron James", and so on.

I tried with `gsub("\.*","", Player)`  but I got the following error:

Error: '.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""."

Then I tried with `gsub("\\.*","", Player)`  and although no error arose, no change was made to the column either.

Finally I tried with `gsub("\\\.*","", Player)`  and got the following error:

Error: '.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\."

How can I do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have to double escape the character you are looking for. Then take it from that character to the end .*$. \1 is the text before the split character.

```
df <- data.frame(Player = c("Kobe Bryant\\kobebryant",
    "LeBron James\\lebronjames",
    "Kevin Durant\\kevinduran"))
df$Player <- gsub("\\\\.*$","\\1",df$Player)
```